# Localization / internationalization tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm looking to add localization to a web site (asp.net /c# if that makes a difference) with a minimum of effort. I've looked at tools like [wiztom](http://www.wizart.com/en/index.shtml) [multilizer](http://www.multilizer.com/) and I am curious as to others experience with them.

Have you used tools like these successfully and if so, what would you do differently?

Comment: This should be on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (I know, that site did not exist when the question was asked - just for future reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with making localized applications I can say that there really isn't an easy, shrink-wrapped solution to this problem. Your best bet is to do a lot of reading on the topic (Google is your friend) and figure out a solution that works best in your specific instance. I think you'll have an issue with the "minimum of effort" part when it comes to localization.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following:

1. Alchemy Catalyst
2. Trados
3. Globalyzer
4. Lingobit

Which you use depends on what you're looking to do:

Are you looking for a tool to help you with string externalization alone (internationalization), or to help you manage the translation/localization workflow?

How big is the application (# of pages, classes)?

Has it been internationalized?

Are you planning to do the localization (translation) in-house or outsource it?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Reading your posting, I think you are looking at internationalization (i18) and Localization (L10n), which are kind of separate. 
i18n is refactoring code so it behaves properly in different locales (language/country, like French in Canada for instance). i18n happens before L10n, because you want to move hard code strings into resource bundles for instance. It's a software eng world.
L10n is usually not done by software engineers, more by translation companies; what they do then is translate text and so on. To do so, they use specific tools: Trados and Passolo are probably what you are looking for.

If you talk about code, it may not be that "simple", because depending on your target locales  you want to address, you may have quite a bit to deal with. For instance, if you stay with France Italy Germany Spain (FIGS in 1i8n parlance), you by-pass a bunch of issues, Japanese imperial calendar, UI redesign for left to right languages, or even encoding of files and data exchange etc.

You may have to deal with locale-sensitive methods (methods which may give you troubles for a particular language/country locale), like text ordering (alphabets are not the same everywhere, so is the order in which we look for words). You WILL have to move hard code user visible text in resource files (for L10n). You may have to deal with encoding issues (you know, ASCII vs. UNICODE for instance, which UTF, etc.).

In that world, check out Lingoport's Globalyzer, it 'looks' at your code and then comes up with potential issues directly in the source, so you can take actions; it guides the actions to take, or prioritize the issues, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Sisulizer to work well. We use it for .net Forms apps but they claim it works for most any app.